# Transfering an entry and all its relations to another Access DB VBA

Tags: mysql, database, vba, ms-access

I've just been assigned the task to create another Access DB whose data is a subset of the master DB. I didn't build the original DB and I'm just stuck in trying to create this functionality.

Depending on a Boolean value (which I will have to integrate into the DB) each entry will dictate if all the entries data will be shared or if only a portion of the data will be shared. By sharing I mean transferring the entries into a mirror DB that is located in a folder that a wider group of people has access to.

I don't know how to even start but I'm guessing that the relations structure that the person who built the DB will be helpful for when I erased an entire entry in the DB it erased all data in other tables related to my entry as well.

For added "fun" I'm suppose to manage a C.R.U.D. system for this subset in case either a person accidentally clicks on the share button (Create) and wants to unshared the data (Delete) or when part of the original gets updated and the mirror then needs to get updated as well (Updated).

I'm hoping to get a few good ideas as to how to proceed.

Limitations and Info that I see might be relevant.

-The original DB is located in a folder whose permissions are restricted to people entering data.

-Can't use third party applications that require an install.

-The mirror DB does not have to updated automatically when the master DB updates. It can be restricted to when a user clicks a button called "Updated Mirror DB". (Only if this would provide a simpler solution)

-The process can be as slow as molasses in winter as long as it is robust.

-I have decent VBA skills when it comes to working in Excel but it lacks when related to Access.

-Users who create and manage the data have read and write access to both the folder that the master DB is in and as well the mirror DB.

-Using Access 2007 - 2010

Thanks everyone for take a look at this. If you would require more info to provide assistance please just ask and I'll do my best to acquire it.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is wall of text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing as you have decent vba, and you're limited to apps which don't require an install, I suggest you do it as an excel vba app. VBA has all the functionality you'll need to copy databases from one spot to another on the file system, compact and repair (adox), drop tables you don't need, insert/update/delete etc.

Depending on which info you need to persist to the mirror db, it may be easier to simply make a copy of the master db and delete irrelevant tables (if it's only certain tables you need to mirror). If it's a subset of data in each table, you may find the best way would be to make a template db, which is a copy of the master db but with no data, then create a vba process to copy the template db, create linked tables in this one back to the master, then run sql to insert into the local tables select (whatever data you need to mirror) from the master tables.

All of this can be done in vba, and your users end up with an excel interface which will be very familiar. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks. I've taken that approach but I've hit a small bump if you will with a permission error. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27436898/permission-denied-in-copying-db-after-connection-closed
Thanks for the reply.