# Permission denied in copying DB after connection closed

Tags: vba, ms-access, database-connection, adodb

I've been trying to copy paste a db and change a few entries.

I believe I'm almost there but I hit a problem.

It seems that I can copy my db no problem until I connect with it. 
During my connection (which makes sense) or after I close the connection I am no longer able to copy and paste the DB as I did before.

I'm pretty sure there is a phantom reference to the connected (but now closed) db remaining somewhere in my code for on my first run through of the code I get the error on the second copy and paste but after that the error jumps up to the first copy and paste. That is until I close access and reopen it. At that point the error returns to the second copy and paste.

I hope this makes a little sense to someone and they can point me in the right direction.

Question: How do I clear all reference to a connection after I'm done with it.

Code Sample

```
Sub Transfer()

'Connection related to DB that contains the master data
Dim ori As Object
Set ori = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Dim oriLoc As String
oriLoc = "Path\RAUMain.accdb"

'Connection related to DB that will host the data.
Dim dest As Object
Set dest = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Dim destLoc As String
destLoc = "Path\Mirror DB\RAUMain.accdb"

'Location and connection that the DB will duplicated and stored until sensitive data is removed
'This is to prevent the case that an error in removing sensitive data would leave the db
'in a location where people would be able to see data that they are not suppose to.
Dim temp As Object
Set temp = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Dim tempLoc As String
tempLoc = "Path\tempRAUMain.accdb"

'Duplicate ori DB
Call DuplicateDB(oriLoc, tempLoc)

'Clear all Sensitive Data from tempDB
'All entries that don't have the share field
' marked as true will be stripped of sensitive data

Call ClearSensitiveData(temp, tempLoc)

'Duplicate the temp data into the destination location
Call DuplicateDB(tempLoc, destLoc)


End Sub



'Duplicates the DB so to insure all data is accurate.
Sub DuplicateDB(oriLoc As String, destLoc As String)

Dim fso As Object
Set fso = VBA.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
dbFile = fso.CopyFile(oriLoc, destLoc, True)

End Sub


'Duplicates the DB so to insure all data is accurate.
Sub DuplicateDB(oriLoc As String, destLoc As String)

Dim fso As Object
Set fso = VBA.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
dbFile = fso.CopyFile(oriLoc, destLoc, True)

End Sub

Sub ClearSensitiveData(ByRef con As Object, dbLoc As String)

'Connect to the DB
Call Connect(con, dbLoc)

    'Code Clear sensitive data

con.Close

'con.Quit
End Sub

Sub Connect(ByRef con As Object, ByVal Loc As String)

Loc = Loc & ";"

On Error GoTo UpdatePublicDatabase_OpenError
con.Open _
        "Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};" & _
        "Dbq=" & Loc & _
        "Exclusive=1;" & _
        "Uid=admin;" & _
        "Pwd=;"
On Error GoTo 0

Debug.Print "Done."
Exit Sub

UpdatePublicDatabase_OpenError:
Debug.Print "Exclusive 'Open' failed. Quitting."
Exit Sub

End Sub
```

Thanks for taking the time to read and ponder this question.

EDIT: I just noticed that I never mentioned on which line the error occurs. 
The error happens the second time I call Sub DuplicateDB on line

```
dbFile = fso.CopyFile(oriLoc, destLoc, True)
```

and the error is Run-time error '70': Permission Denied

Comment: Looking at the scope of your connection object, temp, it is declared and set in the Transfer() sub, so it should ideally be Closed at the end of that sub. Same with your other connection objects. I wouldn't close it in clearsensitivedata because it's not declared there, and you may want to keep using it after clearsensitivedata. close them all before the end of the transfer sub.

Comment: I just tried to move my connection code inside ClearSensitiveData so that it would open and close in the same sub (I got rid of the other connections for the moment) but I'm still getting the same error. It seems that once I connect to the db even if I close the connection something lingers preventing me from copying / moving the db file.

Comment: I have also tried adding
    Set con = nothing 
right after I close the connection and that didn't solve the issue.

Comment: If I comment out the line Call ClearSensitiveData the code runs fine.

Comment: Nice work. Yeah you shouldn't need any open connections in order to move the file, only when you're actually reading/writing to the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change my con.open from

```
con.Open _
    "Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};" & _
    "Dbq=" & Loc & _
    "Exclusive=1;" & _
    "Uid=admin;" & _
    "Pwd=;"
```

to

```
con.Open _
        "Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};" & _
        "Dbq=" & Loc & ";"
```

And it seems to work now.